# Join com soma no Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Estou tentando trazer um resultado em JSON do meu banco de dados.

```
 $products = DB::table('products')
    ->join('order_product', 'products.id', '=', 'order_product.product_id')
    ->select('products.sku', 'products.name', 'order_product.quantity')
    ->get();
    return response()->json($products);
```

Resultado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que estou querendo fazer agora é somar a quantidade vendida de cada item, como devo fazer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consegui realizar a operação.

Segue código;

```
$products = DB::table('products')
    ->join('order_product', 'products.id', '=', 'order_product.product_id')
    ->select(DB::raw('products.sku, products.name, sum(order_product.quantity) as sales_quantity'))
    ->groupBy('products.sku')
    ->get();
    return response()->json($products);
```